# SELECT b.[count] FROM b WHERE b.timestamp > a.timestamp For Each Unique Value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Solution at the bottom.**

I have two tables: one with records of manual inventory counts, the other with inventory receiving counts.

Inventory Count Table:

| timestamp | item_id | units_counted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23/06/22 | 352465 | 137 |
| 27/06/22 | 761697 | 65 |
| 29/06/22 | 352465 | 102 |

Inventory Received Table:

| timestamp | item_id | units_received |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24/06/22 | 352465 | 60 |
| 26/06/22 | 352465 | 72 |
| 28/06/22 | 352465 | 24 |
| 29/06/22 | 761697 | 21 |
| 30/06/22 | 352465 | 96 |
| 02/07/22 | 352465 | 36 |

I am trying to create a view that will show the latest record for each item_id from the 'Count' table.

I am then trying to UNION these with records from the 'Received' table WHERE their timestamp is greater than the latest 'Count' record of the same item_id.

Desired Output:

| timestamp | item_id | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29/06/22 | 352465 | 102 |
| 30/06/22 | 352465 | 96 |
| 02/07/22 | 352465 | 36 |
| 27/06/22 | 761697 | 65 |
| 29/06/22 | 761697 | 21 |

At the moment, I've put together the following query:

```
SELECT
  a.[timestamp], a.sales_item_id, a.sales_item_name, a.unit_cost, a.unit_count, a.unit_cost_total, b.sales_subcat_name, b.sales_category_name, b.sales_department_name
FROM
  [DB].[dbo].[inventory_count] as a
  LEFT JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Inventory_Categorized] as b
  ON a.sales_item_id = b.sales_item_id
WHERE
  [timestamp] = (SELECT MAX([timestamp]) FROM inventory_count i WHERE i.sales_item_id = a.sales_item_id)

UNION ALL

SELECT
  a.[timestamp], a.sales_item_id, a.sales_item_name, a.unit_cost, a.units_received, a.unit_cost_total, b.sales_subcat_name, b.sales_category_name, b.sales_department_name
FROM
  inventory_count as c,
  inventory_received as a
  LEFT JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Inventory_Categorized] as b
  ON a.sales_item_id = b.sales_item_id
WHERE
  a.[timestamp] > (SELECT MAX([timestamp]) FROM inventory_count i WHERE i.sales_item_id = a.sales_item_id)
```

Which takes the single newest timestamp from count, rather than the newest for each item_id.  I am hoping the community can point me in the right direction.

Thanks everyone.

EDIT:  Thanks to @CaptainPsycho, I was able to head in the correct direction and arrive at a functional solution, which is as follows:

```
WITH cte_count AS (
    SELECT [timestamp],
           sales_item_id,
           unit_count AS units,
           sales_item_name,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sales_item_id
                              ORDER BY [timestamp] DESC)
                        AS row_number
    FROM inventory_count
) SELECT [timestamp], sales_item_id, units, sales_item_name
FROM cte_count
WHERE row_number = 1

UNION

SELECT r.[timestamp], r.sales_item_id, r.units_received AS units, r.sales_item_name
FROM inventory_received AS r, cte_count AS c
WHERE r.[timestamp] > c.[timestamp] and c.row_number = 1

UNION

SELECT r.[timestamp], r.sales_item_id, r.units_received AS units, r.sales_item_name
FROM inventory_received r
LEFT JOIN cte_count c ON c.sales_item_id = r.sales_item_id
WHERE c.sales_item_id IS NULL
```

It may not be great, but it's doing the job, and I learned something!

Thanks to everyone else as well for the time, effort, and consideration.  What an amazing community!

On to the next task ;)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. First, in the "counts" table, the combination of timestamp and unit_id is unique (no duplicates) - correct? Then: you need a query that will select, from this table, for each unit_id, the row with the most recent timestamp. In addition, the query must also include rows from the "received" table: for each unit_id, only rows that are more recent than the most recent date (for that unit_id) in the "counts" table. Correct so far? Then: what if a timestamp in the second table is **equal to** that from the "counts" table - include it, or not?

Comment: And, assuming that rows may exist in the "received" table for a unit_id that doesn't appear at all in the "counts" table, what do you need then? (It would make sense to include ALL the rows for that unit_id, all coming from "received", in the output; but this is something your users must instruct you regarding desired handling.)

Comment: Which database engine are you using? Solutions can be differents depending on that.

Comment: @CaptainPyscho SQL Server has been tagged right from the start.

Comment: @mathguy You are right on the money.  Regarding your second question, where there is no record in the 'counts' table, ALL records in 'received' table would be included.  


I was using an ISNULL to accomodate this in the second block, however that was just part of trying to hack my way to a working solution as I learn along the way :)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `row_number()` function to generate a row number for each timestamp per item and then filter the top 1. I put that query in a common table expression (CTE) we can reuse.

```
WITH inv_count AS (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY [timestamp] desc) number, 
            [timestamp], item_id, units_counted
    FROM    inventory_count
)
SELECT  [timestamp], item_id, units_counted units
FROM    inv_count
WHERE   number = 1

UNION

SELECT  r.[timestamp], r.item_id, r.units_received units
FROM    inventory_received r
        inner join inv_count c on r.item_id = c.item_id
WHERE   r.[timestamp] > c.[timestamp]
        and c.number = 1
```

A detailed explanation about the `ROW_NUMBER()` function [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/)

Comment: Thank you so much @CaptainPsycho.  I was able to use this as a starting point to figure out exactly what I needed!  Mission Accomplished!

Answer (score 0):

A little ugly, and I'm sure a more efficient way is possible, but pretty sure this would get you the results desired (might need extra handling for timestamps that match between your counts and received tables to resolve collisions):

```
select
    timestamp,
    item_id,
    units_received as units
from
    inventory_count
where
    (item_id, timestamo) in (
        select
            combined.item_id,
            max(combined.timestamp)
        from
            (
                select
                    item_id,
                    timestamp
                from
                    inventory_count
                union
                select
                    item_id,
                from
                    inventory_received
            ) combined
        group by
            combined.item_id
    )
union
select
    timestamp,
    item_id,
    units_received as units
from
    inventory_received
where
    (item_id, timestamp) in (
        select
            combined.item_id,
            max(combined.timestamp)
        from
            (
                select
                    item_id,
                    timestamp
                from
                    inventory_count
                union
                select
                    item_id,
                from
                    inventory_received
            ) combined
        group by
            combined.item_id
    )
    order by item_id, timestamp;
```

Answer (score -1):

Items from the table 'count' have the same id but different date and 'count number', you just need the latest one for each id.so, the key is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT timestamp, item_id, units_counted
    FROM `count`
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
)
GROUP BY item_id
```

The code above will only left the latest time for each id and
work in MySQL, not sure whether it will work in SQL Server.

Comment: The syntax is not valid for SQL Server - please ensure your answer is in the technology requested.